# CMake does not include .h file when generating build script for a IDE?

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, cmake

I want to use cmake to generate native build scripts for visual studio platform.

So I creat a CMakeLists file to generate the build script on visual studio.
Everithing go well when I generate but when I open the project and I build it on visual studio, all my .h file are not found.

After reading tutorial on CMake configuration my CMakeLists seem's to be good, I do not understand.

Here is my CMakeList.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)


#Projet

 project(SignalProcessing)


#Liste des fichiers sources

 file(

    GLOB_RECURSE

    source_files

    ../../../RefFT/Float/src/Test/*
    ../../../RefFT/Float/src/Vector/*
    ../../../RefFT/Float/src/Filter/*
    ../../../RefFT/Float/src/Math/*
    ../../../RefFT/Float/src/Transform/*
    ../../../RefFT/Float/src/SSTP/*
    ../../../RefFT/Common/src/*
    ../../../../../../../Generic/Common/Include*
    ../../../../../../../Generic/X86/Include/*
    ../../../../../../../Tools/Malloc_3DSL/RefFT/Common/Source/*
    ../../../../../../../Tools/Malloc_3DSL/RefFT/Common/Include/*

 )

#executable

 add_library(

    SignalProcessing

    STATIC

    ${source_files}
 )
```

So this file will creat me a Microsoft studio solution.
And when I build the solution I get error like this :

```
Erreur  13  error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier include : 'target_assert.h' : No such file or directory C:\Users\Admin\Documents\HOA\open\ContentEnhancement\3DSound\AudioLibs\SignalProcessing\RefFT\Float\src\Vector\SIGPROC_VECTOR_algebra_32f.c ligne 33 colone 1   SignalProcessing
```

the target_assert.h file is in :

```
 C:\Users\Admin\Documents\HOA\open\Generic\X86\Include
```

Why is he not found, he is in the `CMakeLists.txt` file

Comment: Does it matter though, since `.h` files aren't compiled?

Comment: I gues yes the project doesn't compile beceause of those "file not found"

Comment: How are you including those headers? Perhaps you need to add an inclusion directory.

Comment: It is not a project failur, this project works and compile. I just want to re-creat the build script to see how CMake works beceause I will have to do the same on projects that doesn't compile on visual studio

Comment: Without seeing an actual error message, and any related code, one can only *guess* what is wrong.

Comment: Yes sorry i'll edit my question

Comment: You'll have to add `C:\Users\Admin\Documents\HOA\open\Generic\X86\Include` as an inclusion directory, using either [`include_directories()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/include_directories.html) or [`target_include_directories()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/target_include_directories.html). Alternatively, `#include "..."` with a relative path. As for ‘*Why is he not found, he is in the CMakeLists.txt file*’: You've specified *source files*, that has nothing to do with how header files are found. And it's the same whether you use CMake or configure VS by hand.